# Is there a source for tzitzis being referred to as "the jersey of kings"?

Tags: tzitzis

A song (Rachamana, by Ta Shma featuring Matisyahu) refers poetically to tzitzis as "the jersey of kings" - is there a source for this or a similar expression?

Comment: What's the Hebrew for this expression? Most classic Jewish literature is in Hebrew so it's hard to find English quotes.

Comment: The closest Hebrew I can think of is בגדי מלכים. But, I've never heard that term used for *tzitzit*. If anything, the most common Hebrew term I've heard for a garment that has *tzitzit* is טלית קטן. While here the word קטן means "small" it can also mean "humble". Sounds like a contradiction to the notion of pomp and circumstance befitting a king!

Comment: I think בגד מלכים is close but a pity it wasn't used to describe tzitzis.

Comment: Maybe because the king of king's "wore" it http://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.17b.5?lang=bi it became the king's clothing

Comment: Tefflin are a crown (for king's) so I guess the tzitzis are the jurzy מצוין בציצית ומעוטר בתפילין and kitzur yalkut yosef "מעוטר בטלית ותפילין"